# markdown code block in a specific color

Tags: highlighting

I would like to highlight a code block per instance completely in yellow.

```
ˋˋˋyellow
here is everything printed yellow
ˋˋˋ

ˋˋˋgreen
and here is everything green
ˋˋˋ
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at `:help syntax`. You'll probably have to write syntax patterns for the regions that interest you, and highlight the corresponding syntax groups accordingly.

Comment: Mh... I tried to

:syntax region yellow start=/```yellow/ end=/```/
:hi yellow ctermfg=yellow

but text did not turn yellow. What di I get wrong?

Comment: You can check the syntax groups that apply under the cursor in a variety of ways, _e.g._, `zS` from scriptease, my own https://github.com/benknoble/vim-synstax, etc.

Comment: Hi Ben,
I installed your plugin, but it seems to be for investigating syntax. How can this help  me to make blocks in a specific color?

Comment: The idea was to check the syntax groups to make sure your region was actually applied; if it was not applied, then it would make sense there was no yellow highlighting. It's possible the default markdown syntax rules are overriding your region; I'm not sure of the best way to have your region take priority.